# Retrieving Friend's Friends List and Retrieving relationship_details from another user

Tags: facebook, relationship, friend

Is it possible to do the following: Retrieve Friend's Friends List and Retrieve relationship_details from another user (it is possible to see "interested in" while viewing someone's profile.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

You will need to ask for 
`user_interests` and `friends_interests`
also 
`user_relationship_details` and `friends_relationship_details`

Comment: I read this, but note that I'm looking for a friend of a friend. Not my friend. How about the second part of the question? And why would I need interests if I have relashionship_details?

Comment: You can't.  That's more deep than the current permissions allow.  Also the user_interests is for "it is possible to see "interested in" while viewing someone's profile" as I thought you asked if it is possible.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry the permissions don't allow you to get the information you're after.